# Can i put an .jsp inside a modal pop up

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, iframe

I have listUser.jsp, it has a link that "calls" user.jsp. user.jsp have a form that saves in my DB and listUser.jsp shows it. The problem is: i want user.jsp to open in a modal, is that possible? i've tried iframe inside the modal, but when i Submit in user.jsp, inside the iframe, it "returns" to listUser.jsp and doesn't close.
      with the iframe i've tried this (didn't work):

```
<script>
  function yourFunctionName () {
    var div = document.getElementById('dialog');
    if(document.getElementById('noop').src === 'user.jsp'){
      div.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      div.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
</script>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    setInterval(yourFunctionName, 1000);
  }
</script>
```

i'm learning, so i don't know much

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for this purpose,

listUser.jsp

```
<div id=content></div>
```

Use jquery instead of yourFunctionName (), like this

```
document.ready(function(){
    $('#button').on("click", function() {
      $("#content").load(absolutePath/user.jsp);
   });
});
```

hope this will helpful!